# how to write json data in to json file in assets folder in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development.In my application i wants to write json object in my json file which is existed in assets folder on save button click.

Please help me to go forward.

Thank you,
Srinivasarao.ch

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629730/how-to-write-json-data-to-a-file-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Android's `Assets` folder is read-only at runtime, write to card, it is possible to save the data in your `Shared Preferences` as well.